# onCreateOptionsMenu showing alwasy as action with a menu that i have created programatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-optionsmenu, oncreateoptionsmenu

Below is how i have created my menu programmatically

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);


 menu.add(0, 0, 0, new SetUpClass().menuInitializer(
     Objects.requireNonNull(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireActivity(),R.drawable.ic_cart)),
                getResources().getString(R.string.cart)));

}
```

Below is my menuInitializer method in SetUpClass

```
public class SetUpClass {

public CharSequence menuInitializer(Drawable drawable, String title) {

        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("    " + title);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return spannableString;
    }

}
```

How can i make the programmatically created menu to always show as action like when using xml menu like below

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: Did you try `menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS` to set menu item as always visible

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);


MenuItem menuItem =  menu.add(0, 0, 0, new SetUpClass().menuInitializer(
     Objects.requireNonNull(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireActivity(),R.drawable.ic_cart)),
                getResources().getString(R.string.cart)));
menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);


}
```